# How do I convert a column of 3-letter amino acids to 1- letter amino acids in excel w/ biopython?

Tags: python, biopython

I'd like to convert a column of three letter amino acids in excel to one letter and print out the one-letter amino acids to each corresponding row in the excel file. I understand I can use `biopython` for this.

What I've Tried:

```
import Bio
from Bio.SeqUtils import seq1
seq1("MetAlaIleValMetGlyArgTrpLysGlyAlaArgTer")
'MAIVMGRWKGAR*'
```

But I want it to be understood that I cannot put a string for python to convert. I need to read a whole column in excel and print a new column with the converted 1-letter sequence. The picture for reference:

[image: example]

Comment: what have you tried so far to open the data? your example doesn't attempt to read any inputs

Comment: i'm not sure how to open and read data

Comment: Read the xcel file line by line converting data into string and then use biopython on the string. Otherwise you need to create your own dictionary that matches 3letter code with one letter code and use the same approach

Comment: Try from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for old xls files, I managed code below, works with your example saving a copy
of your file with the new column. I understand that pandas library can manage xlx and newer version in a better way. Let me kno it it works for you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Sat May  1 15:24:42 2021

@author: Pietro


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271713/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-3-letter-amino-acids-to-1-letter-amino-acids-in-ex#comment119033760_67271713

"""

#import Bio #not needed

from Bio.SeqUtils import seq1


# Reading an excel file using Python

import xlrd   #read xls library

from xlutils.copy import copy  #copies xls library

## from xlwt import Workbook # writes xls library ##not necessary
 


loc = ("inputz.xls") # input xlx same directory of python script
 


wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) #open xls file

wb_copy = copy(wb) #copy of your xls file

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) #select sheet of input file

sheet_copy = wb_copy.get_sheet(0)  #select sheet of copy file



lenght_rows = sheet.nrows #number of rows in input file 

print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0)) # prints sheet 0 cell 0,0 of input file 

print(lenght_rows) #prints number of rows of input file

# loops over row (0,1 to 0, number of rows) of input file
# 
# and use biopython to convert 3 letter into 1 letter 
# writes 3 and 1 letters to copy xls file

for i in range(1,lenght_rows):   
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), '   :  ' , seq1(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)))
    sheet_copy.write(i,0,sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    sheet_copy.write(i,1,seq1(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)))
    
wb_copy.save('output.xls') #saves xls output file
```